# Translating a float to a negative or positive

Tags: c++, c

I have a `float` from `0 to 100` and I want to translate that into a number from `-20 to 20` an example:

`float` is `100` then translated it would be `-20`

`float` is `50` then translated it would be `0`

`float` is `0` then translated it would be `20`

What is the best method of doing this?

Comment: Wow so many answers, it makes me feel like I don't now math :(

Comment: This is pretty fundamental maths; you should probably brush up on basic algebra if you want to be a productive developer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*[I'm going to give you the approach to figuring this out, rather than just the answer, because it'll be more useful in the long-run.]*

You need a linear transform, of the form `y = mx + c`, where `x` is your input number, `y` is your output number, and `m` and `c` are constants that you need to determine ahead of time.

To do so, you need to solve the following simultaneous equations:

```
-20 = m * 100 + c
+20 = m * 0   + c
```

Note that I've picked two of your required transformation examples, and plugged them into the equation.  I could have picked any two.

Answer (score 3):

How about this: `(50. - x) * 0.4`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do:

```
20 - val * 0.4
```

Comment: You should multiply by 0.4 instead, to avoid floating-point division.

Answer (score 1):

```
 float procent = (myval - 50)/2.5f;
```

use `(int) floor(procent)` if you need integers...

Answer (score 1):

```
float translate(float f)
{
  return 20.0f - ((20.0f * f) / 50.0f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is called "Linear interpolation" and can be done in a general function like this:

```
float linear_interpolate(float x, float x0, float x1, float y0, float y1)
{
  return y0 + (x - x0)*((y1-y0)/(x1-x0));
}
```

In your case you would call it like (replace x with your in value):

```
float value = linear_interpolate(x, 0.0f, 100.0f, -20.0f, 20.0f);
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation for a reference article.

Answer (score 0):

```
((x / 2.5)- 20) * -1
```

this should do it

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the slope. Since you have already 3 points (0, -20) (50, 0) (100, 20), you can do dx = 40/100 = 2/5 (change in y / change in x) and b = -20. Then you define a function (f(x) = mx + b) f(x) = (2/5)*x - 20, 0 <= x <= 100.